# I Have a listview how to connect that to another activity

Tags: android, listview

I'm lost, so can I please have some help on how to link the list items to seperate activities?I just want to be able to do an action when I click on the row, with the data that the row contains of course any ideas? thanks
main.java:

```
package com.sevenhack;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class Main extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        setListAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, 
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, R.id.textView1,
                getResources().getStringArray(R.array.itemlist)));
    }

private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId,
            String[] strings) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, strings);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.itemlist, parent , false);
        String[] items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.itemlist);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        TextView tv = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv.setText(items[position]);



        return row;
    }

}
```

}

---

layout>itemlist.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    >


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:src="@drawable/ic_securee"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:text="Large Text" android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"    
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp" android:textSize="20dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

thanks.

Comment: be more clear about what you want to do..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is the following:

1.) Implement the onListItemClick function of the ListActivity.

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
{
   super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
   MyItem myItem = (MyItem) this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
   ... //will need to add more things here
}
```

2.) Your 'MyItem' class must implement the Parcelable interface. This can be automated with the Parcelabler, here: http://www.parcelabler.com/

3.) Send the item to the new Activity in an Intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("argument", myItem);
startActivity(intent);
```

4.) In your other activity, get the Parcelable from the Intent.

```
public class OtherActivity extends Activity
{
   private MyItem myItem;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle onSaveInstance)
   {
      super.onCreate(onSaveInstance);
      this.myItem = (MyItem) getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("argument");
      ...
   }
}
```

5.) Do what you want with the item in the other activity, such as display its data. For that, specify the layout XML, and in onCreate(...) function find the views by ID and set their parameters based on item received in Intent.

EDIT: Here's a sample I put together based on your stuff which works:

```
public class MyListActivity extends ListActivity
{
   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setListAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.itemlist, R.id.textView1, getResources()
            .getStringArray(R.array.hello_world)));
   }

   @Override
   public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
   {
      super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
      String myItem = (String) this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class);
      intent.putExtra("hello", myItem);
      startActivity(intent);
   }

   private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
   {

      public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, String[] strings)
      {
         super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, strings);
         // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
      }

      @Override
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
      {
         LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)     getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
         View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.itemlist, parent, false);
         String[] items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.hello_world);
         TextView tv = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
         tv.setText(items[position]);

         return row;
      }
   }
}
```

Next step:

```
public class OtherActivity extends Activity
{
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      String data = getIntent().getExtras().getString("hello");
      System.out.println(data);
   }
}
```

/res/values/array.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="hello_world">
        <item name="hello">Hello</item>
        <item name="world">World</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

/res/layout/itemlist.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"    
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp" android:textSize="20dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.exa.ex.testproject"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.exa.ex.testproject.MyListActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.exa.ex.testproject.OtherActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: I tested but did not work,can u replace my code? thanks

Comment: You have an error in line:  "android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, R.id.textView1",  what you want is "R.layout.itemlist, R.id.textView1"

Comment: Sorry That is simple_list_item_1 not 2!what can I do?

Comment: I put you together a sample, I removed the ImageView to put it together more quickly, but other than that it's pretty much the same.

Comment: Thanks very much!but when i tested i see all listview items only link to SecondActivity.java,what should i do for each Item link to its activity for example ItemList1 goes to One.java,ItemList2 goes to Two.jva and...?? thanks again

Comment: In that case, you need to specify the class you want to start by changing the parameter in the Intent, rather than just start a specific Activity. I assumed you were sending the data to a "detailed" activity rather than use this as a selection method for a Menu between Activities. In that case, I'd almost think about adding my own object that stores the Class<?> to which the Intent sends the program, and the toString() would return the activity's name. I'm just rambling here at this point, you should specify what exactly you want to do.

Comment: I am very amator can U Give an example for this?Sorry.Thanks

Comment: This is getting long in this discussion, basically what you need is to start intents based on the data stored in the list. So the XYZActivity.class depends on the condition what is stored in the clicked list. It's literally this, except instead of running OtherActivity, you make an if-elseif structure. That's the simplest (albeit not the prettiest) way of doing it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement `onListItemClick(....)`. You directly override this method in your `Activity`.

```
  @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)          
  {
     super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    // ListView Clicked item index
    int itemPosition=position;

     // ListView Clicked item value
   String  itemValue=(String)l.getItemAtPosition(position);

   Toast.makeText(yourActivity.this,"Click :Position :"+itemPosition+"ListItem : " +itemValue,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();;

    }
```

When Click on `list item` then `onItemClick` method in `ListView Item Click Listener` called
and then Passed selected value in you `Intent`.

Comment: I tested that but only show: Click: position: {number}ListItem
I want go to second activity!