# ListView example program which switches to new activity

Tags: android

Could anyone possibly give me an entire example for demonstrating a ListView.
Each item in listview needs to fire a new activity.
For ex, if I use 'Subjects' as content of ListView then after pressing particular a subject from listview , a new screen with its title and some content of that subject gets displayed.
I know this is too much to ask, but i have been looking for ListView Ex. since quite long and nothing has helped me so far. PLease Help
Thank you

Comment: Use `switch case` with its `position` in `onItemClick` method of `ListView`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23994445/2413303

Comment: To be honest, just creating a new project with minimum SDK level of 11 and target SDK 19, with navigation type of "Master/Detail flow" and you'll have your answer. o.o

Answer (score 0):

you can refer following link for listview demo code.

http://www.androidhive.info/2011/10/android-listview-tutorial/

and for opening new activity on selecting any item, you can use,

```
    listCoupon.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            // here you can compare selected item by its position and then start a new activity

//   arg2 is selected item position in your arraylist

        }

    });
```

Comment: you can write Intent myIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, , NextActivity.class);
startActivity(myIntent);

Answer (score 0):

```
yourlistview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {


            }
          });

then use bundle to send some content to your next activity. 
then getActionBar.setTitle(sometext); this text is come from your bundle.

This contains:
http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-search-listview-using-filter/
```